# Is the 12-6 Lennard Jones potential a good description of van der Waals interaction energy?

Tags: bond, computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics

It seems to me that the Lennard Jones potential oversimplifies the more complex nature of van der Waals forces. However, in most of the MD simulation package, this is generally accepted.

Comment: Of course LJ is not precisely accurate, but it is computationally cheap. This makes it good enough for many applications.